# document.body.scrollHeight yielding two different results in firefox/chrome

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to get access to the height of the entire page (including scrolling). In chrome, document.body.scrollHeight does this. In firefox, this doesn't work... what is the equivalent in firefox?

Comment: With a scrollbar, it doesnt. jQuery takes care of it thought.

Comment: did you find a solution for FF ?

Answer (score 1):

definitely start using jquery, accessing $(document).height() will do all the browser checks for you.

http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to do this without browser problem.

User jQuery  `$(document).height()` and `$(document).scrollTop()` functions

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var scnWid,scnHei;
if (self.innerHeight) // all except Explorer
{
scnWid = self.innerWidth;
scnHei = self.innerHeight;
}
else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight)
// Explorer 6 Strict Mode
{
scnWid = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
scnHei = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}
else if (document.body) // other Explorers
{
scnWid = document.body.clientWidth;
scnHei = document.body.clientHeight;
} 

</script>
```