# iframe height cut off

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, iframe

Im working on a page, containing an iframe and i have a major problem in firefox.
Im using this javascript for iframe sizing:

```
<script language="JavaScript"> function autoResize(id){
var newheight;
var newwidth;

if(document.getElementById){
    newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
    newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
}

document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";    }
```

```
<iframe src="https://like-coppers.de/kundenbereich/" scrolling="no" border="none" width="100%" height="100%" name="CHANGETHIS" id="CHANGETHIS" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onload="autoResize('CHANGETHIS');" onresize="autoResize('CHANGETHIS');"></iframe>
```

on chrome it works perfect(ignore border): [image]
but on firefox it gets cut off: [image]

Do you know a solution for this?

Comment: In Firefox you need to query `documentElement.scrollHeight` instead of `body.scrollHeight`

Comment: @CBroe it works perfect!!! thank you so much.

Comment: can you submit it as answer so i can mark it as right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox you need to query `documentElement.scrollHeight` instead of `body.scrollHeight`

---

Methods to automatically choose the correct property can be found in
[.body.scrollHeight doesn't work in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932650/body-scrollheight-doesnt-work-in-firefox) or
[document.body.scrollHeight yielding two different results in firefox/chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857341/document-body-scrollheight-yielding-two-different-results-in-firefox-chrome)

Comment: Its now working in firefox, but in chrome it doesnt resize anymore: http://imgur.com/a/lhXSY I changed body.scrollHeight to documentEelment.scrollHeight

Comment: You need to take both values into account; check the other questions I linked to, they have examples how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put inline style to fix this issue style="overflow:hidden;min-height:600px;width:100%"

So your iframe will look like

```
<iframe src="https://like-coppers.de/kundenbereich/" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" scrolling="no" border="none" width="100%" height="100%" name="CHANGETHIS" id="CHANGETHIS" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onload="autoResize('CHANGETHIS');" onresize="autoResize('CHANGETHIS');" ></iframe>
```

Hope this help you